# What is a good place in Goa to stay with a beach and scuba diving?

Tags: planning, india, beaches, diving, goa-india

We are going to Goa with small children and are trying to find a nice beach resort, but with a decent dive shop, so that the adults could also do some diving. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The best season for enjoying water sports and scuba diving in Goa is from October to May. It's the season when the skies are cloudless and blue and the water remains placid.

**SUN VILLAGE RESORT** -India's only 4 star fully inclusive resort is beautifully set on the slopes of Arpora hills overlooking picturesque salt lakes and rice fields. With 135 well appointed air-conditioned suites, conference facilities, gala buffets, theme entertainment and a choice of exciting cuisines from mouth watering barbeques to Goan delicacies, this resort offers excellent facilities and a diver friendly pool. Complimentary TRY SCUBA sessions are conducted every Monday morning. Fun for all the family, join our team of Instructors to experience your first breath underwater.

**CHALSTON BEACH RESORT** - Overlooking the Arabian Sea along the ever popular Calangute-Baga beach, Chalston offers an ideal holiday spot for divers and families who wish to stay close to the main activity hub of Goa yet still relax in the comfort and tranquility of this friendly, family run resort. Enjoy warm hospitality, sunset cocktails and a choice of Indian or Continental cuisine at the Chalston Beach Shack. Complimentary 'TRY SCUBA' sessions are conducted every Monday afternoon. Our team of Instructors awaits you at the poolside coffee bar for scuba fun, a cappuccino and a slice of freshly baked walnut cake!

**SINQUERIM**: With a magnificent 17th century fort which has now been converted into a prison. It is one of the best beaches in Goa with international class facilities for water-skiing, para-sailing, fishing, scuba-diving and wind-surfing.

Comment: -1 because the *entire* answer was copy-pasted off the web. (The intro from http://www.scubadivingingoa.com/scuba-diving-vacations-goa.php and the rest from http://www.barracudadiving.com/accommodation.php) @Jaguar: You can quote relevant stuff from websites but you should clearly indicate what you wrote and what you quoted (and from where).